# Magento is sending the original order along with the order filled status email

Tags: cron

We have a Magento e-commerce website. When an order is filled, we upload an xml file to our web server and a cron job is run that checks the contents of the folder for these xml files and then updates the status of the customer's order in their account on the website. In addition to updating the status, an email is sent to them notifying them that the order is complete and has been dispatched. This is correct, however in addition to the status filled email, they are also receiving a copy of the original order. This is not correct as they don't need to receive this order as they already have the original copy.

I wondered if anyone could tell me if there is a setting in the Magento backend that can switch off this duplicate order email so that the customer only receives the confirmation email that their order has been sent? Or is this hardcoded in the cron job?

Really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can select which email to send upon which action, using System > Configuration > [Sales: Email]. Additionally you can alter the templates and add it remove information using System > Transactional Emails.

Answering on my phone, so it may actually be the other way around, but those are the two back-end paths dealing with them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went to System > Configuration > Sales Emails, then under the Shipment heading, next to "Shipment Email Template", "New Shipment (Default Template from Locale) is chosen from the Dropdown menu. Then next to "Shipment Email Template for Guest", "New Shipment for Guest (Default Template from Locale)" is chosen. So can you let me know which one of these templates is the one that's sending the duplicate order? Also, within those two drop down menus, there's another option which is called "newsletter subscription success new". So it seems that you have to choose a template.

Comment: Both. You can find them in `app/locale/en_US/template/email`. And you can edit them in the backend using the other path. See the tutorial here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails

Comment: Thanks for the file path but I just need to know how to disable the duplicate order email being sent at the same time as the order fulfilled email. Can you let me know how to do this?

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear, you mean for the same action, two emails are sent? That sound like your processing saves the order twice with a different status, firing two events. To know which two are firing I'd need to know what the status changes are, but...this is best fixed in the cron code that handles the fulfillment. Order status changes have a flag to indicate whether to send email. It defaults to true, so when you do two order status changes in one process, you should set it to false on the first change.

Comment: Yes two emails are being sent for the same action. I found the following code in the status.php file:                      }elseif($action_type==7){
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();} It's the only reference to the word "True" that I could find. Not sure if you can help further but if not I may need find someone who can troubleshoot the cron

Comment: The person who built the script should have no problem fixing it. Of course you can always open up a new question with the code of that script.